# Java Spring @Transactional method not rolling back when throw exception

Tags: spring, mybatis, transactional

My config code here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@PropertySource(value="classpath:datasource.properties")
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired private Environment env;

    @Bean(destroyMethod="close")
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driverClass"));
        ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        ds.setInitialSize(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("db.initialSize")));
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

}
```

The @Transactional method:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void create(String orderid, String type, String userid,
            String comment) throws Exception {
        log.info("### orderid={}, type={}, userid={}, comment={}", 
                orderid, type, userid, comment);
        OrderActivity orderActivity = new OrderActivity();
        orderActivity.setActivityid(SeqUtil.produceOrderActivityid());
        orderActivity.setComment(comment);
        orderActivity.setOperator(userid);
        orderActivity.setOrderid(orderid);
        orderActivity.setType(type);
        orderactivityDao.insert(orderActivity);
        //FIXME just for test
        if(OrderConstant.ACTIVITY_CANCEL.equals(type)){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        log.info("###orderActivity=[{}]", orderActivity);
    }
```

In the method *create*, when *type* is ACTIVITY_CANCEL, then throw an exception. But this activity is also be inserted into database, not rollback. Why?

Comment: The database is postgres

Comment: Have you checked that your "orderactivityDao" doesn't have force commit in insert method?

Comment: try add @ComponentScan("com.yourtxpkg") to DataSourceConfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I put AppConfig and b in DataSourceConfig different context. Changed the code like this:

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {AppConfig.class, DataSourceConfig.class, MybatisConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class };

}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { MCVConfig.class};
}
```

Then everything is ok.